# How to create a keyboard shortcut for an input button

Tags: html, jquery, button, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am showing a bunch of pictures and each picture has its own HTML page.  I have an input button that onclick will take you to the next link for the picture.  However, I want to be able to use my keyboard arrows to go forward and back.  I am new to coding and don't know if this is possible.  Can I do this with HTML using the accesskey:

```
<input type="button" accesskey="?" value="Next Item">
```

Or do I need to use a JQuery plugin?  If so, which one?

Comment: If looking for jQuery Plugin - https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button/5061382#5061382) explained, the HTML `accesskey` defines a key that will be trapped only when it is combined with the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key. That is why that is **not useful for trapping any key alone**.

But you have to take special care choosing the event to trap the cursor keys because [Webkit has decided not to trap them with the `keypress` event as it is not in the standard](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7300). At this moment the other 3 answers here use this `keypress` event and that is why they **don't work in Google Chrome nor Safari**, but if you change that to `keydown` they'll work on all browsers.

You can use this jQuery code to capture the `keydown` event of the <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: // left arrow key
    case 38: // up arrow key
      e.preventDefault(); // avoid browser scrolling due to pressed key
      // TODO: go to previous image
      return;
    case 39: // right arrow key
    case 40: // up arrow key
      e.preventDefault();
      // TODO: go to next image
      return;
  }
});
```

And in **the following** *code snippet* you can see and run a complete example in which images are swapped using the keys or the buttons.

```js
var currentImage = 0;
var imagesArray = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Tux.svg/150px-Tux.svg.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/150px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Git-logo.svg/150px-Git-logo.svg.png'
];

function hasPrev() {
  return currentImage > 0;
}

function hasNext() {
  return currentImage < imagesArray.length - 1;
}

function goToPrev(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!hasPrev())
    return;
  currentImage -= 1;
  updateScreen();
}

function goToNext(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!hasNext())
    return;
  currentImage += 1;
  updateScreen();
}

function updateScreen() {
  $('#imgMain').attr('src', imagesArray[currentImage]);
  $('#btnPrev').prop('disabled', !hasPrev());
  $('#btnNext').prop('disabled', !hasNext());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateScreen();
  $('#btnPrev').click(goToPrev);
  $('#btnNext').click(goToNext);
});

var keyCodes = {
  left: 37,
  up: 38,
  right: 39,
  down: 40
};

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case keyCodes.left:
    case keyCodes.up:
      goToPrev(e);
      return;
    case keyCodes.right:
    case keyCodes.down:
      goToNext(e);
      return;
  }
});
```

```css
button:enabled kbd {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnPrev">
  Previous Image
  <br/>
  <small>(arrow keys: <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>up</kbd>)</small>
</button>
<button id="btnNext">
  Next Image
  <br/>
  <small>(arrow keys: <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd>)</small>
</button>
<br/>
<img id="imgMain" src="">
```

### UPDATE (May 2016)

**keyCode** has recently been deprecated (but I haven't found a cross-browser solution yet). Quoting [MDN article for keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> > #### Deprecated
> >
> > This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.
>
> ...
>
> This shouldn't be used by new web applications. IE and Firefox already (partially) support KeyboardEvent.key. Also, Google Chrome and Safari support KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier which is defined in the old draft of DOM Level 3 Events. If you can use them or one of them, you should use them/it as far as possible.

Comment: oh right, I forgot, keypress is really meant to determine which alphanumeric key was pressed (like for typing, as it preserves capitalization keycode), vs keydown is generic input (lowercase keycode is used, but will detect function keys etc).

Answer (score 32):

I just used a third party [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js). It's very friendly. You can [reference](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shortcut.js"></script>

<script>
    shortcut.add("alt+s", function() {
        // Do something
    });   
    shortcut.add("ctrl+enter", function() {
        // Do something
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Great package. FYI: You can reduce the scope of the shortcuts, by supplying an optional `option` object with a `target` property, and a lot more customizations are possible.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it answers the question exactly with minimal effort

Answer (score 9):

> Can I do this with HTML using the accesskey:

No, accesskey is used in conjunction with <kbd>alt</kbd>

So `accesskey="a"` will make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> be the shortcut.

> Or do I need to use a jQuery plugin?

No, you can use regular old javascript; jQuery works too.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  switch ( code )
  {
    case 43:
      //do stuff
      return false;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I did example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/6176/) it uses arrow key up and down so it focuses next or previous input control respectively . Take a look

Answer (score 2):

I will use this :

```
<input type="button" accesskey="n" value="Next Item">
```

And the user should type : shift + alt + n

Comment: OP specifically states that he/she wants to use the arrow keys, not `n` or any other letter.

Comment: Also doesn't appear to work on arbitrary elements (though I can't blame it when people use js click handlers that won't work form any input other than a mouse)

Comment: Just saying, its a different shortcut if you're using a different browser and laptop. You can see which one works for you at : www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could do this...

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {

    case 37:
        prev();
        break;
    case 39:
        next();
        break;

    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xktZt/).