# HTML accesskey 'e' not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, access-keys

I assigned access key <kbd>e</kbd> to email input field in a simple html form. I am currently testing this in chrome. So on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, instead of switching focus to the email input field, the Chrome menu get activated.

How should I go around with this? How to gain focus to the input element on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Anything helpful here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button ... else you should add some code.

Comment: What code should be added? so that the key combination pressed is catched by the web-page and not by the browser itself. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The implementation of `accesskey` attributes is browser-dependent, [see some of the variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key).

It also interferes with the built-in accesskey assignments that browsers or assistive software may have. It is therefore not recommended by accessibility specialists.

On my Chrome, an element with `accesskey="e"` attribute gets focused on, when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. But I would not have known if I had not checked it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#U" id="AU" name="U" title="右上方功能區塊" accesskey="U" tabindex="3">:::</a>
```

Give it a `name="U"`,and `href="#U"` `name=href`, and Chrome will work.