# Simulate a Keyboard shortcut using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, alt

I have a windows application running which takes screenshot when I press "ALT+Z". I want to trigger the same action in HTML/JS; that is the HTML/JS should simulate/trigger a "ALT+Z" so that the windows application takes a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you describe what you want to do with simulating a press of Alt+Z?  This would help us figure out the best way of doing what you want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `accesskey` attribute:

```
<input type="button" accesskey="z" />
```

This will invoke the click when `alt + z` is pressed.

Comment: NOTE: Not supported in Opera according to W3Schools

Comment: Nothing happen... im running another screenshot app in backend. alt + z is my hotkey for screenshot.