# Submit Form by pressing a Key

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form with 4 buttons.  I would like to have each submit button bound to a keypress so that when the keys (a,s,d,f) are pressed it submits the form and passes the value assigned to that submit button.  My goal is to have hotkeys for the 4 separate buttons.  I am stuck, I looked up and learned how to use javascript to see what key is pressed, but I am having a problem passing that key to submit the form.  How can I bind a key to the button to submit the form and pass the value? Thank you for the help.

Here is the solution   *** thanks to those who helped me

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
onload = function(){
document.onkeypress=function(e)
  {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e
  var code=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
  var asciiStr=String.fromCharCode(code);
  document.getElementById("key").value = asciiStr.toUpperCase();
  if(['A', 'S', 'D', 'F' ].indexOf(asciiStr.toUpperCase()) != -1){
    document.getElementById("Ability").submit();
   }
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['S']) || isset($_POST['D']) || isset($_POST['F']) || isset($_POST['key']))
{
$value= $_POST['key'];
    if (isset($_POST['A']) OR $value == 'A')
        {
        echo 'A';
        }
    if (isset($_POST['S']) OR $value == 'S')
        {
        echo 'S';
        }
    if (isset($_POST['D']) OR $value == 'D')
        {
        echo 'D';
        }
    if (isset($_POST['F']) OR $value == 'F')
        {
        echo 'F';
        }
}
?>


<form name="Ability" id="Ability" method="post" action="">
<input class="text" type=text id=key name=key  value="" />
<input type=submit name="A" value="A">
<input type=submit name="S" value="S">
<input type=submit name="D" value="D">
<input type=submit name="F" value="F">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/  Note: `java` is **NOT** `javascript`.

Comment: [**StackOverflow**](http://bit.ly/4Agih5) is **NOT !**, a place to ask someone for free `codes`. 
[Such Questions are **Not Good** for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq), and will be [**Closed**](http://bit.ly/18T95z1), or [**Deleted**](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR), *Instead* [Learn what type](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc)  of questions you can or should ask. If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J), Or check the [FAQ](http://bit.ly/18T95z1), page for general information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button

Comment: @MarcB OP asked for javascript, not jquery.

Comment: I read the above question, but I don't want the user to have to press alt and the key

Comment: @cobra: and jquery is written in... javascript. go ahead and do it in bare javascript and then spend an aeon debugging cross-browser compatibility, or fire up jquery and get it done in 30 seconds.

Comment: @MarcB You can't make someone use a specific framework here. The tag description says `Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.`

Comment: I am teaching myself php, mysql and javascript, I have not used jquery

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8aYd7/).

You need to change the id to the form's id:

```
onload = function(){
document.onkeypress=function(e)
  {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e
  var code=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
  var asciiStr=String.fromCharCode(code);
  document.getElementById("Ability").submit();
   document.getElementById("key").value = asciiStr;
}
}
```

**Update :**
This is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
onload = function(){
document.onkeypress=function(e)
  {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e
  var code=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
  var asciiStr=String.fromCharCode(code);
  document.getElementById("key").value = asciiStr;
  document.getElementById("Ability").submit();

}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['key']))
{
echo 'Worked';
}

echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>


<form name="Ability" id="Ability" method="post" action="">
<input class="text" type=text id=key name=key  value="" />
<input type=submit name="A" value="A">
<input type=submit name="S" value="S">
<input type=submit name="D" value="D">
<input type=submit name="F" value="F">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output :
[image]

**Update 2**
The below code is to always compare to the values you have and always deal with uppercase letters so even if you press a it will be converted to A.

```
document.onkeypress=function(e)
  {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e
  var code=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
  var asciiStr=String.fromCharCode(code);
  document.getElementById("key").value = asciiStr.toUpperCase();
  if(['A', 'S', 'D', 'F' ].indexOf(asciiStr.toUpperCase()) != -1){
    document.getElementById("Ability").submit();
   }
}
```

**Update3**

This is the updated version of the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
onload = function(){
document.onkeypress=function(e)
  {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e
  var code=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
  var asciiStr=String.fromCharCode(code);
  document.getElementById("key").value = asciiStr.toUpperCase();
  if(['A', 'S', 'D', 'F' ].indexOf(asciiStr.toUpperCase()) != -1){
    document.getElementById("Ability").submit();
   }
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['key']))
{
echo 'Worked';
}

echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>


<form name="Ability" id="Ability" method="post" action="">
<input class="text" type=text id=key name=key  value="" />
<input type=submit name="A" value="A">
<input type=submit name="S" value="S">
<input type=submit name="D" value="D">
<input type=submit name="F" value="F">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I see   But My main problem is the post

Comment: What is the problem with the post ?

Comment: I updated my code above.  I can't get the echo to display to say what button is pressed when you press the letter key

Comment: I really appreciate the help I have been stuck on this all day.  I have the id text in their to make sure my javascript code was correct to see what key was pressed

Comment: change your condition to `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: it works fine for me. in your condition you are only displaying if you click `A`

Comment: Mehdi, I really appreciate the help, but it is still not working, I want the echo to occur when I press the letter key on the keyboard not when I press the button. I will work on it some more.

Comment: I think I miss understood your question you need to send A when you key press a or A , I will fix your code , one minute.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in my original post, I am trying to make keys on the keyboard be the submit like hotkeys in a computer game

Comment: take a look now and let me know what you think.

Comment: Ok, one last step different echo based on which key is pressed?  Because in the code if any key is pressed on the keyboard it will echo.

Comment: you can also improve your code bey making key input field a `input type=hidden `

Comment: would this work  if (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['key'] == 'a'))

Comment: it depends what you are sending, with my Update 2 it should be like this:  (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['key'] == 'A'))

Comment: just try it and make your changes based on your needs

Comment: if that resolved your problem don't forget to mark it as the solution.

Comment: I still can not get it to work. I might just have to call it and work on it tomorrow. I really appreciate all the help Mehdi, more than anything I learned more about javascript today, which is the most important thing, thank you.

Comment: So troubleshooting I think I found the problem but having trouble fixing it, for the function it is only passing the keyboard value when the key is pressed down, therefore after I release the key it runs the function with a key value of blank.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about, the function is called each time there is a key is pressed, i just added a condition to avoid processing characters different than the ones you need which are : `'A', 'S', 'D', 'F'` (I am uppercasing all inputs)

Comment: Ok fresh start, up above is what I am working with currently

Comment: The uppercase new code did not work at all when I pressed a button so I just stuck with the lowercase and I am fine with that

Comment: If I press any key on the keyboard I get the result of AS    it is like the keypress is not passing through as a value

Comment: the button code doesn't have any relation ship with the onkeypress code, there should be an typing error from your side. it worked fine for me

Comment: hmmm, can you link the code you are using

Comment: Don't know if it matter but I am using IE 10

Comment: the code is already updated above you just replace the function by the on I have put in Update 2

Comment: if you are using IE take out `console.log` from your code, it was used for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with me.  Ok my code is updated in the question section.  When I press any of the buttons I get   ASDF as the output.  The code does not respond at all when I press a letter key.  I have tried it in both Firefox and IE and get the same result

Comment: ok I will post my last code.

Comment: Same issue, I really appreciate the help, I am going to look into another way to do this. I really do appreciate your time

Comment: It works except their is no difference between pressing A,S,D,F  I need them to echo different values not the same value.

Comment: GOT IT! I can just post the value to a variable after the submit and use the variable, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I use this construction for my projects

```
<input id="your_id" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) submit_function()">
```

pretty easy.

You need a keycode for your buttons.

Comment: Thanks I am playing with this method to see if I can get it to work

Comment: @JoeCurnow if you write what you exactly need, I'll help you. I don't understood what you want from your question and from comments to another answer.

Comment: I want to have 4 buttons that have assigned keys  a,s,d,f.  When you press that key on the keyboard I want the code pass that letter as a variable so that I can use it for code further on.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoeCurnow hope, i did. Check Mehdi answer as a correct, he help you very much.