# Most efficient way to pause a HTML Marquee without a mouse

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, marquee, spacebars

As the title says, im needing to pause some scrolling text in a html marquee.

It is used on a small laptop next to the camera as a scrolling script for me to read basically, the scroller works great and is super simple, but obviously i wouldn't be at the laptop so cant stop it if i need to pause if i start rambling on about something else in the middle of the script or whatever reason.

My original thought was to get a small bluetooth keyboard (since there rather cheap) and have it on the floor where i stand which will also leave my hands un-interrupted. I can then pause and play the scroller without any problems.

So i guess the question is, could i pause it with the keyboard spacebar with javascript for example, if so, how?

Here is my marquee (this is a remake of it since the original is on my laptop):

```
<body style="styles-here">
<marquee style="styles-here" behavior="scroll">
    TEXT TO SCROLL
</marquee>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should not use the `<marquee>` tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Its nothing public and will only be used for text to scroll so i can read it, its all local on my laptop. What else would you recommend me using? The marquee seams to be working exactly how i was wanting so far. I just want to be able to pause and play using a keyboard spacebar (or any other button).

Comment: It looks like a `stop` method is available for marquees

Comment: I know how to stop and start the marquee using buttons, but how would i tie them buttons to a keyboard press?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `stop` and `start` methods

```js
var state = 'play';

function toggleMarquee() {
    var marquee = document.getElementById("marq");
    if (state === 'play') {
        marquee.stop();
        state = 'stop';
    } else {
        marquee.start();
        state = 'play';
    }

}
```

```html
<marquee id="marq">This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleMarquee();" value="Toggle" />
```

**EDIT**

To add keyboard shortcuts to buttons please see here: [How to create a keyboard shortcut for an input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! although i am looking to have it stop/start with a key press (any key on a keyboard really but mainly  the spacebar is needed)

Comment: @haydenbarton96 see my answer edit. There are lots of posts on stackoverflow about how to trigger events on keypress

Answer (score 1):

```
  <marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">my text here</marquee>
```

This should do the work requested.

Thanks
Pav