# jQuery submit button accesskey issue in the IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a problem in jQuery, that causes event handler bound via document not to fire, when the accesskey is used.
The code sample for the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnOK", save1);
            $("#btnOK").on("click", save2);
            document.getElementById("btnOK").addEventListener("click", save3);
            $(document).on("click", save4);    
        });
        $(document).on('submit', function () {alert("Submitting the page"); });

        function save1() {
            alert('1');
            //return false;
        }
        function save2() {
            alert('2');
           // return false;
        }
        function save3() {
            alert('3');
            //return false;
        }
        function save4(e) {
        console.log(this, e)
        if (e.target.id === "btnOK")
            alert(4);
        //return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <button id="btnOK" name="btnOK" accesskey="S" ><u>S</u>ave</button>&nbsp;
    </form>
</body>
```

As you would presume, when we click a button (using mouse button) in IE11, we get the sequence of messages: "2", "3", "1", "4", "Submitting the page". Then, it would be rational for the page to show the same behaviour if we "click" the button, using accesskeys. **But you would be wrong.**
All we get is "2", "3", "4", "Submitting the page".
Despite the fact, that "click" event is exactly the same (except for button and buttons properties, but that doesn't matter), we register the click event with

```
$(document).on("click", save4);
```

but not with

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnOK", save1);
```

Does anybody know, how to fix it? Not using IE11 is *not an option*.

Comment: You don't click it though - try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061353/how-to-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-an-input-button and http://methvin.com/access/

Comment: @JanuszJasinski Thank you, but I actually know that you need a combination of alt+key/alt+shift+key(for FF). The thing is - one event does trigger, and the other one doesn't

Comment: i can confirm, sounds like a bug in IE11 (only)

Comment: Have you tried adding the handlers in a different sequence? i.e. You've defined them: Document, Id, Element, and Function; try reordering the code lines to a different order... maybe Document ("save1") last? I'm betting IE isn't bubbling the event up to the document once the other handlers have completed.
            `$("#btnOK").on("click", save2);`
            `document.getElementById("btnOK").addEventListener("click", save3);`
            `$(document).on("click", save4);`
             `$(document).on("click", "#btnOK", save1);`

Comment: @millebi thanks for commenting, i actually forgot about this thread. I found out, that it was a bug in jQuery, after contacting administrators @ their official forums. I've also filled a bug report on IE site, but as far as i'm concerned it was flagged as "won't fix"